# Why did Bartholomew Kuma allow Vegapunk to turn him fully into a pacifista?

Tags: one-piece

> Kuma seems to have a good enough relationship with Vegapunk. Vegapunk was able to grant him his final wish as a human being, which was to program Kuma to protect the Straw Hats ship until their return. It is very likely that Vegapunk highly respects Kuma's strength, as he modified Kuma to be the prototype Pacifista, and he let Kuma do things that go against the World Government, as well as granting him his last wish by including a mission into his programming that Kuma himself had requested.

It is even shown that the bible he holds is his trademark. If that is true why would he sacrifice his consciousness along with his humanity if he lived life cherishing something that very much so represented humanity, freedom and free will?

If he much admired the prospect of free will, going as far as wanting his last wish to protect the Straw Hats ship, why would he even agree to losing his humanity and getting modified to a fully-fledged Pacifista?

Is it ever mentioned or is it just some extremely personal relationship stuff shared between Vegapunk and Kuma?

Comment: I don't think it's been revealed yet

Comment: aww disappointing :/

Comment: it might turn out that kuma owed vega punk big time so he had to repay it this away!! :P

Comment: It might be Dragon who ordered him too. Or maybe he felt so guilty for the horrible things he did in the past, that he wanted to pay for his sins to serve the WG fully by catching criminals.

Comment: Kuma is a part of revolutionary army. He only checked the willpower of Luffy's nakama(Zoro) that Zoro can serve his Captain though he could have captured Straw Hat Luffy's Crew. Sengoku talk with him about it with Garp.Kuma used his power to protect Straw Hat Luffy's crew from Kaizuru and transfer them in different place. This is treason. He is against Marine. So he is punished, this may reason. His replica was use to build Pacifista. Vegapunk may have seen something with Kuma's body.Using original one to build powerful pacifista(PX-00). These are not official but concluded from different arc.

Comment: @mirroroftruth it was not punishment for helping strawhats. he stated before even helping them that he will be fully transformed soon and lose sense of himself (I think it was during the war to Ivankov).

Comment: @Quikstryke At the war Kuma was already a Pacifista. He told Rayleigh during his fight with Kizaru that he didn't have much time and wanted to help the straw hats, so indeed, it can't be punishment for that time.  I also doubt it to be punishment for letting the people at thriller bark live, as he was already part Pacifista by that time. Time will tell what the real reason was he changed.

Answer (score 3):

An explanation is that after rescuing straw hats at sabaody, he was defeated by Kizaru and captured in seastone cuffs. After that he probably received death penalty, but since hes a pacifista project he was probably sent to vegapunk to have his brain removed.

His capture and punishment was not mentioned somewhere in the manga/anime.

However, this is a VERY PLAUSIBLE theory on why Kuma was turned into a full pacifista. Certainly a more plausible theory than the 'he did this for dragon', or 'dragon ordered him to do so' nonsense theories that are floating around in this discussion, neither of which are mentioned anywhere in canon either.

It is highly unlikely Kuma was willingly turned into a full pacifista. Some people posted here that 'he did this for Dragon', 'Dragon ordered him to do so'. What? How would doing so benefit Dragon and revolutionaries? How would it benefit Kuma himself (obviously won't since he would be dead?) What other POSSIBLE incentive that world govt offered him or the revolutionary that could be so great, that it would outweigh the consequence of him being dead? Probably none. Therefore it leads to conclusion that the government forced that choice upon him. Straight up executing him most likely wouldn't have been an attractive option, since they would need as many shichibukai on their side to face against whitebeard. Therefore all these points toward my theory - that Kuma was punished for opposing the marines and an admiral from carrying out the order to purge the tenryuubito's attackers. Thats why world govt most likely decided to fully transform Kuma into a pacifista in order to both punish him and turn him into a fully loyal slave.

Kuma was certainly aware that this would be his punishment, thats why he stated that this will be the last time he will meet the strawhats.

Vegapunk most likely was in a good relationship with Kuma and likely did not want to turn him into a full cyborg either, but he had to do so under the pressure from the world govt. Thats why Vegapunk likely programmed in Kuma's request to protect the Sunny.

Comment: This is at best pure speculation, then again, every answer is pure speculation, because we know the answer exists and we know it was not revealed yet.

Comment: How did he become in the side of the government if he is in dragon's side? If he is there to help the strawhats, why did he have to take luffy's pain and give it to zoro as an option of letting luffy live??

Answer (score -1):

I believe Kuma did this for Dragon. If Vegapunk does not like the WG we could see Vegapunk give control of the pacifista and Kuma when the time comes. I dont think he would willingly do this to help the wg as he directly opposes it.

Comment: interesting theory.  I can see his willpower overcome the programming at some point and take control of the other Pacifistas, or maybe Franky has a hand in awakening his true self.

Comment: Dragon definitly Knows why kuma did it, as he said it over the den den mushi to ivanakov or whatever the Newkama's name is, which i forget right now. Vegapunk is also a scientest, he's intelligent, probably knows about the corruption of the WG and might be secretly and slowly helping the revolutionary army, or may not really care whos in charge, so long as he gets to do his science stuff, but probably has some code he live by to allow this to happen.

Answer (score -2):

well first things first, he's one of the Revolutionary Army, and I thinks he's willing to do everything for the sake of their Army, willingly turning himself into a Pacifista "may be" a voluntary action by himself to earn the full trust of the WG (again, he willing to do everything for the army's sake right??) and on my understanding, Dragon is a very good leader and would not force his nakama like Kuma to be a cyborg just for the army..and on that finals request to Vegapunk for his final modification, it is still unclear why Vegapunk allow that to happen since he's under the WG and knows that Luffy is a pirate, he must really respect Kuma as a colleague so he grant his request or knew Dragon or Garp in the past to grant that kind of request which is of course against the WG ideals.