# Why does Bartholomew Kuma support the world government?

Tags: one-piece

Bartholomew Kuma is a former revolutionary and a friend of Monkey D Dragon. So why is he helping the government instead of helping Dragon. We know that he helped Luffy and his crew during the Sabaody Archipelago Incident, and also helped them to keep the Thousand Sunny away from pirates and the world government. But still he offered himself to the government so that they could turn him to a complete Pacifista.

Comment: Some of the members here still haven't watched the entire series so it's just an alert for them that's all :)

Comment: How about now :)

Comment: Not sure if it is a duplicate, but certainly related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6518/1604

Comment: Partially related

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ Surely related, but unlike the other question asking why he turned into a Pacifista, and his connection between Vegapunk. This question sounds more like why did he turn a pacifista instead of going back to the revolutionary?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he was an informant for Dragon but he was too honorable to betray the government bluntly.
We know that he was a man of reason when he let Zoro take up all the pain instead of Luffy.

Him becoming Pacifista was entirely for different reasons which we still don't know.
He offered himself to be experimented upon but his last wish was to protect thousand sunny which was honoured and his wish was fulfilled.